# How to calculate angle between two 3d vectors onto x-y plane

Tags: vector

Vector1 (-0.241844763,-0.664463024, 0.707106781)
vector2 (0.5,0.5,0.707106781)

I can see the CAD system reported that is 155 degree on X-Y plane.
How to calculate it by programming?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the angle that describes the rotation of each vector using the inverse tangent of the ratio between y and x (given you want the one on Oxy plane).
Then you can just subtract the angle of one vector to the one of the other:

```
atan2(vector1.y, vector1.x)-atan2(vector2.y, vector2.x)
```

where `atan2` is usually defined as

```
atan2(y, x) {
    if(x==0) {
        if(y<0) {
            return PI/2;
        } else {
            return -PI/2;
    } else {
        angle=atan(y/x);
        if(x<0 && y>=0) {
            angle+=PI
        } else if(x<0 && y<0) {
            angle-=PI
        }
        return angle;
    }
}
```

returning an angle between -PI and PI; thus it spans the whole circle instead of only half.

Comment: obviously, to get it in degrees, you have to take `angle*180/PI`; the name of PI or the namespace in which you find the function and whether `atan2` is defined at all  depends on the language you plan to use